# Clone a View to perform an animation

Tags: android

I have a problem in my app. I want to translate a View(Button) when i press it from point A to B but keeping the original View in their original place.
Now i have two buttons declared in my layout, one is the view fixed and the other is the view that realize the animation. The problem is that if I press two times the same button, the first animation disappears before finish it and starts one new. I want that the animation ends always although I press the button many times. I thought clone the view and translate it every time I press the button but I dont know if this is correct.
How can I do this effect in the right way?

Comment: Disable the click as long as the animation is running...

Comment: But i dont want disable the click, is part of the functionality. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: if(!animRunning) startAnim();

Comment: Do you got any success here? I also want to add translate animation but on clone by keeping the original as it is